# Send Mail without password in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I am working on one Asp.net application. I have one **Email Reminder form** in which my Client's Email ID & checkbox is provided. Admin will select the checkbox & press the **send reminder** button & the mail will be sent to all the checked checkboxes i.e. to my clients.but in this form I have one Textbox say **Sender** in which Admin will put sender Email ID & from that Email ID all the email will be sent to my clients.

How can I send mail without password as admin can use any email ID from our company email IDs as per his requirement. How can I achieve this

here is my code

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "smtp.office365.com",
                    Port = 25,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Adminsupport@abc.com", "123456")
                };
                var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
                mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("Adminsupport@abc.com");
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.Body = body;
                    //"Email from : <a href='mailto:" + from + "' target='_blank'>" + from + "</a><br/>For Form Name : ";
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(tomail));

                smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

                mailMessage.Dispose();
                smtpClient.Dispose();
```

Comment: if your Email server requires a password to authenticate, you cannot go round it.  If your account doesnt have the rights to "Send as" its unlikely to work.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845060/send-an-email-using-smtp-without-password-in-c-sharp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1):

Create a new user for the sole purpose of sending mail from your web application, and configure its credentials in your application.

Then configure that user so it may send on behalf of the user or group you want to let the email originate from.

You can use SMTP Client Submission or SMTP Relay, see [How to set up a multifunction device or application to send email using Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4).

Comment: currently we using "Create a new user for the sole purpose of sending mail from your web application, and configure its credentials in your application."

Comment: but how i can achive this 
"Then configure that user so it may send on behalf of the user or group you want to let the email originate from."

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it sounds like you want one of two things.

You either want to spoof the email address, in which case you will actually change the From header field. This will show the recipient the email address and name that you desire.

```
mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mycompany.com", "Steve James" );
```

The other possible answer is that you want to actually to send the email from your own login credentials, but have it be sent 'from' an account that you have exchange permissions to send from. (This is an MS Outlook / Exchange specific answer) - You would need to send via the MS Outlook interop API

```
 // Retrieve the account that has the specific SMTP address. 
        Outlook.Account account = GetAccountForEmailAddress(oApp , "support@mydomain.com"); 
        // Use this account to send the e-mail. 
        oMsg.SendUsingAccount = account;
```

This would ensure that only someone who has appropriate permissions to send 'from' an address, can do so - as it offloads the authentication levels checking to MS Outlook.